# Create a list referencing object in another list

Tags: c#, list, reference

using c# I have read an XML file into an XML document and I use XPath to get a list of XMLNodes in an XMLNodeList codelist. I am wanting to create a separate List BlankCodes that has reference to any XmlNodes in codelist that meet a criteria.

so my current code that creates a list of XmlNodes of interest looks like the below.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("C:\\Test.XML");

List<int> blankCodes = new List<int>();

XmlNodeList codeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("codelist\\Code");
foreach( XmlNode aNode in codeList)
{
  if(aNode.Value == "")
  {
    blankCodes.Add( (int)aNode.Attributes("Index")
  }
}
```

I will then iterate through the integers in the blankCodes list and find the corresponding node in the codeList again and modify another value in the node.

is it possible to essentially create a list of Pointers to the appropriate XmlNodes in codeList? then rather than having to find XmlNodes in codeList by xPath or looping through I can reference the XmlNode directly?

I am more than happy to try and provide clarification if you can guide on what needs clarifying.

Many Thanks bommelding.

------Demo code of working answer below -----------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestReferences
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Basic Class to with index and value
    /// </summary>
    class aVal
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create two lists of class to simulate XML node
            List<aVal> originalList = new List<aVal>(); //Proper list as if read from XML
            List<aVal> blankList = new List<aVal>(); //List of Blank Codes

            //Loop to create 20 instances of class
            for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                //Create class
                aVal temp = new aVal();
                temp.Index = i; //Index 
                temp.Value = i * 2; //Easily Identifiable Value

                originalList.Add(temp); //Add to original list

                if( i == 4 || i==12 || i == 18) //Simulate Blank Codes
                {
                    blankList.Add(originalList[originalList.IndexOf(temp)]); //Add the instance to blank list so we get a reference, 
                    //I presume that I have to add the one in the list not the temporary instance used to populate the original list
                }

            }

            //Write the original list to the console
            //Expected output "Index 1 : Val 2"
            Console.WriteLine("******* Original List ***************");
            foreach( aVal te in originalList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Index {0} : Val {1}", te.Index, te.Value);
            }

            //Write the blank list to the console.

            Console.WriteLine("******* Blank List ***************");
            foreach (aVal te in blankList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Index {0} : Val {1}", te.Index, te.Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("*****************");
            Console.WriteLine("Modifying Blanks");
            Console.WriteLine("*****************");

            //Set each instance.value to -99 referenced by the blanklist
            foreach (aVal te in blankList)
            {
                te.Value = -99;
            }

            //Check the output, 4,12,18 should have value -99
            Console.WriteLine("******* Original List after blanks modified ***************");
            foreach (aVal te in originalList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Index {0} : Val {1}", te.Index, te.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `myList.Add(aNode)`

Comment: Side note but make sure you know about XDocument . A lot of XML problems are a lot easier with that API.

Comment: To be honest. I have never seen any question edited in acknowledgment of selected answer showing how beautifully it works !!

Comment: But here `blankList.Add(originalList[originalList.IndexOf(temp)]);` are you sure that you cannot do better than this ?

Comment: I feel that if someone gives you a partial answer then the time taken to create a demonstration is worth it. as for the adding the reference to the item just added if you have a nicer way feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: try `blankList.Add(temp);` instead of `blankList.Add(originalList[originalList.IndexOf(temp)]);`  and run your program and also tell me what do you get to know out of it

Comment: ok that works but why, because temp is essentially destroyed the next time round the loop, how does it create the link between blankList and originalList? when you `originalList.Add(temp)`  does it not create a new instance in originalList

Comment: @PhilCrowder actually it is temp's reference that both lists are holding.. when you add temp into main list.. then too main list is holding just reference of temp. now when you add temp to blank list you are passing same reference to blank list.. when you create new Temp, then temp holds different instance (different reference) but those reference which were stored in list will stays alive..

Comment: @Amit - I suspect that deep down c# is dereferencing the pointer "temp" to the last instance of aVal, yet somewhere in the belly of the beast the original instance is still kept which permits the linking between the lists. I have just tried with "aVal" being structure rather than a class but the linking between the lists is broken in this case

Comment: @philcr yes, structure is value type while class is reference type. after last instance of aVal, temp will not be accessible outside of the loop. for sure.. but reference of the objects will be linked with lists.. and thus memory allocated for this objects will not be released till list are not out of the scope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because XmlNodes are normal C# objects. You always work with (through) a reference.

Creating a copy of an instance is a lot more work, especially for the XmlDocument family.

```
List<XmlNode> blankCodes = new List<XmlNode>();


  if(aNode.Value == "")
  {
     blankCodes.Add(aNode);
  }
```

Comment: To clarify does this create a reference to the aNode or just create a copy of aNode which is then added to my List

Comment: It simply stores the reference. Creating a copy (clone) takes some effort.